# Java EE: NoClassDefFoundError org.joda.time.DateTime with IntelliJ and Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jodatime

I am using IntelliJ 14

I want to add joda.time lib in my project.
When I add this lib manually (copy the jar file into lib repository, and add reference in Project Structure) everything work good, I can use the library in a servlet and show the result in a jsp.

But in second step I create the same project but I am using maven with a pom.xml file. I add this dependency :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Maven download automatically the lib, in my Project Structure every thing looks like it's good, I run the project ... no error, but when I go to my webpage I have an error in my navigator :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime
com.sdzee.servlets.ServletTest.doGet(ServletTest.java:47)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The project is exactly the same, I just use Maven for use the lib.

Do you have ideas?

My Servlet line 47 for example :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    Integer jourDuMois = dt.getDayOfMonth();
}
```

Comment: please consider upvote of my answer in case it solved your problem.

Comment: click the up arrow left of my answer please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check in your `pom.xml` if the `packaging type` is explicitly set to `war`. If not, maven won't use the maven-war-plugin to bundle your application correctly with all your referenced libraries, e.g. `joda-time`.

so You should have:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

See also for reference: 
[Maven Reference Book](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-package-specific.html)

Answer (score 3):

Thank MWiesner, you for your Answer. It work.

I found another solution:

- In IntelliJ / Project Structure (F4 Key) / Artifacts
- On the right (Available Elements) there is the joda-time library, i must double click it fo transfer the lib in the artifact.

I dont know if is it possible for IntelliJ to do that automatically when maven import the lib ?

Comment: if you activate the "Enable Auto-Import" feature of the maven integration in IntelliJ, then libraries/dependencies should be synced with your pom.xml and Intellij Project Format automatically

Comment: The Auto Import was Enable in Maven Settings. This option add automatically the lib in "Modules" and "Libraries" tab but not in "Artifact"
I dont know Why

Comment: This was also the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more likely the joda-time jar is not included when you deploy the project. You can unzip the war file and see if it's there. I use Eclipse, which installs Maven plugin. So when I export the Maven project, all the Maven managed jars will be included in the war.