# Spring Data Envers - PropertyReferenceException: No property findRevisions found for type Foo

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I do have a Sprint-Boot application and try to add `hibernate-envers` or to be more specific `spring-data-envers` to the project.

So I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The Revision entity is successfully generated/created and it was saved until I tried to user the RevisionRepository. Now I get errors I did not expect.

I created a new configuration like:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.package.entities"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.package.repos",
repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class EnversConfiguration {}
```

And I extended my already working CrudRepository by:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface FooRepository extends RevisionRepository<Foo, Long, Long>, CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
    ...
}
```

Anytime I try to start the application it tells me:

```
SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'repositoryFactoryBeanClass' for annotation [unknown] was not resolvable due to exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes.assertNotException(AnnotationAttributes.java:544)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes.getRequiredAttribute(AnnotationAttributes.java:429)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAttributes.getClass(AnnotationAttributes.java:293)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.getRepositoryFactoryBeanName(AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.java:216)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.getRepositoryFactoryBeanName(DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder.build(RepositoryBeanDefinitionBuilder.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:83)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.package.web.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:49)
```

The configuration is included like:

```
@Import({ ... , EnversConfiguration.class})
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
   ...
}
```

So I found somewhere a hint that `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.package.repos"` is not needed twice, cause I got already another Configuration for the JpaRepositories, so I deleted it from `EnversConfiguration`

After that I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$LocalVariableTableVisitor.resolveMember(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:245)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$LocalVariableTableVisitor.visitEnd(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:231)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1172)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:729)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:527)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:114)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.buildPreferredConstructor(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.<init>(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ReturnedType$ReturnedClass.detectConstructorParameterNames(ReturnedType.java:286)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ReturnedType$ReturnedClass.<init>(ReturnedType.java:233)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ReturnedType.of(ReturnedType.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.<init>(ResultProcessor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.<init>(ResultProcessor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.<init>(JpaQueryMethod.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:449)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:222)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 133 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.DateTime
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 162 common frames omitted
```

Because of some @Autowired injection of the FooRepository in a FooService:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fooServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fooRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime
```

Just to be sure I added the following dependency to the pom.xml and checked if packaging is set to "war"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Update 1** (Original title: ClassNotFoundException: EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean or org/joda/time/DateTime)

So I played a little bit around and changed the order of the imported configurations:

```
@Import({EnversConfiguration.class, DataAccessConfiguration.class, ...})
public class WebApplication
```

Afterwards I splitted FooRepository to FooRevisionRepository and FooRepository staying just a CrudRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRevisionRepository extends RevisionRepository<Foo, Long, Integer> {}
```

No I get this error when starting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fooServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fooRevisionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooRevisionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.springframework.data.repository.history.RevisionRepository.findRevisions(java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property findRevisions found for type Foo!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 110 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fooRevisionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.springframework.data.repository.history.RevisionRepository.findRevisions(java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property findRevisions found for type Foo!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 123 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.springframework.data.repository.history.RevisionRepository.findRevisions(java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property findRevisions found for type Foo!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:101)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:449)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:222)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 133 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findRevisions found for type Foo!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:70)
    ... 143 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Yeah I checked the packaged .war file and the 'joda-time-2.9.9.jar' is included in the lib folder

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28637628/1004631

Comment: Already read that and it did not help - sry

Answer (score 2):

Configure jpa repositories: 
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class
)

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good answers on SO. Can you please modify your answer to provide some context about how to use your code, and in addition, format your code (using a set of ``)